# error in styles in API8 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-styles

could anyone please help me with this?
I opened an existing project and I get this error in the screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you tell what is the error at least?

Comment: Error: No resource found that match the given name: "android:Widget.Material.ActionButton"
I did according the instruction: http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a style which require API 21. You are referencing a style called `Widget.Material.ActionButton`. So you need to put this reference in a v21 directory to use the CompatLibrary which I would recommend.

The real cause seems to be that you have a very low target SDK (like you wrote in the comments API 8). You should set it to the most newest one, it cannot break anything. So set the target SDK to API 21 or newer and it should work fine.

Comment: http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Eclipse
The instruction says it should be like this:  "Build Target -> check Android 2.2
"

Comment: I reviewed your screenshot a second time, what is your target SDK? I guess something below API 21?

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the project, but the minimum SDK is assigned to 7. I'm following steps in http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Eclipse

Comment: Well I forgot how to set that in eclipse, since I use now Android Studio since about 2 years. The point is that I guess that you build your app for let's say Ice Cream Sandwich (API 14), but that SDK uses special styles for Lollipop (API 21), so you needs to build your project against a newer (Android) SDK. Just to make sure I'm not talking about the minimum SDK just the target SDK.

Comment: It's API8.
I added to the main post the picture that shows where you select build target.

Comment: Try to set it to API 21, then it should start working.

Comment: But I want it would work for lower version of Android. As I told before, I did what the instructions said. I know that those themes might not be supported in API 8. Do you think there would be anyway that the code would work in API 8?

Comment: The target SDK is something different then the minimum SDK version. You define the minimum version in the manifest btw. So it will still work on that legacy devices.

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe I lack some basic knowledge. I thought target SDK is to ensure that the App would work with the latest versions, and minimum SDK, well, to show that it will work with minimum SDK! So I guess logic says it should also can be built with the minimum SDK. Did you get where I got confused!?

Comment: The minimum SDK is the version you require at least. The target SDK is the API you are building against, but you need to make sure that you don't use API calls which are not supported on the device. There are so called lint warnings which help you to avoid those calls on older platforms.

Comment: As you said at least. So it should work with API 8 and API 21. That's what min and target SDK are for. Plus, I should say, the website mentioned that it would work with API 8, so I'm looking for what is missing.